# Android - Facebook SDK login -> logout -> login not working

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I have an Android application (very simple one, just starting to learn the basics). I've implemented Facebook login, which is almost working perfectly. Starting the app first time everything works just fine: pressing the login button, asking for permissions, logging in, then the app shows the authenticated page for the user. When pressing the logout button it shows me the login page again, so that works too. Now when I try to log in again it doesn't work. It opens the facebook stuff again for some seconds then it just goes back to the login page like nothing have happened. If I remove the permissions on facebook for the app and try log in again it works again. So for some reason I can't log in when I already have the permission I guess...

Here is the code:

```
package com.just.simply.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;

public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final int SPLASH = 0;
    private static final int SELECTION = 1;
    private static final int SETTINGS = 2;
    private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = SETTINGS + 1;

    private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];

    private boolean isResumed = false;
    private MenuItem settings;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragments[SPLASH] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.splashFragment);
        fragments[SELECTION] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.selectionFragment);
        fragments[SETTINGS] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.userSettingsFragment);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
        isResumed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
        isResumed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        // Only make changes if the activity is visible
        if (isResumed) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            // Get the number of entries in the back stack
            int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
            // Clear the back stack
            for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
                manager.popBackStack();
            }
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                // If the session state is open:
                // Show the authenticated fragment
                showFragment(SELECTION, false);
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                // If the session state is closed:
                // Show the login fragment
                showFragment(SPLASH, false);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.equals(settings)) {
            showFragment(SETTINGS, true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // if the session is already open,
            // try to show the selection fragment
            showFragment(SELECTION, false);
        } else {
            // otherwise present the splash screen
            // and ask the person to login.
            showFragment(SPLASH, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // only add the menu when the selection fragment is showing
        if (fragments[SELECTION].isVisible()) {
            if (menu.size() == 0) {
                settings = menu.add(R.string.settings);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            menu.clear();
            settings = null;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private Session.StatusCallback callback =
            new Session.StatusCallback() {
                @Override
                public void call(Session session,
                                 SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                    onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
                }
            };

    private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            if (i == fragmentIndex) {
                transaction.show(fragments[i]);
            } else {
                transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
            }
        }
        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! If any other files needed just ask.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the second time you're also performing a successful login, but you don't need to confirm the permissions again. I'm also starting to use Facebook SDK, but I think it is the cause.

Comment: As far as I can tell the problem is that when I press the login 2nd time state.isClosed() is true. I just don't understand why.

Comment: Found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256467/facebook-seession-is-closed-after-log-in-process-in-android -- it works now.

Comment: Glad to know it, I'll take into account if I face the same problem.